# почему CI_COMMIT_TAG пустой?

Tags: gitlab, tag, pipelines

я работаю в гитлаб, запускаю pipline где написано

```
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
  only:
    - tags
  tags:
    - gitlab-runner-tag
```

runner находится на моем компьютере. Как мне получить тэг версии который я делаю вот так в консоли:

```
git tag 1.8.2
```